# Change database.location from command line

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way to specify a Neo4j database location at command invocation time, instead of via a file? So instead of putting the following in `neo4j-server.properties`:

```
org.neo4j.server.database.location=/path/to/db
```

Something like:

```
neo4j --db=/path/to/db
```

I'm still on Neo4j 2.1.6 but advice on any version is better than nothing.

My particular use case at this time is, my regular DB is having problems and I want to quickly spin up a blank database just to narrow down the problem to binaries or data (yes I've checked the log files!).

Comment: It seems `neo4j-shell` supports `-path` but `neo4j` server does not.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `sed` to edit `neo4j-server.properties` before starting neo4j. Something like:

```
sed -i.bak s/org.neo4j.server.database.location=databases/org.neo4j.server.database.location=newdatabase/g neo4j-community-2.1.6/conf/neo4j-server.properties
```

You could create a simple script that takes the path as a param. So something like:

`./start-neo.sh mytestdb` where `start-neo.sh` is:

```
sed -i.bak s/org.neo4j.server.database.location=databases/$1/g neo4j-community-2.1.6/conf/neo4j-server.properties
neo4j-community-2.1.6/bin/neo4j start
```

will set `org.neo4j.server.database.location=mytestdb` and then start neo4j.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'd prefer not to do that because I want to leave my last known working state untouched. Another solution I had considered was a here-document, but even specifying an alternate config file from the command line is not possible.